# How do I calculate selected item from list-box with text-box value to output it in textbox through button

Tags: c#

each value of list box has 2 values
one string name of the pizza other is int the price
the user will chooses pizza and enter the amount through textbox and press calculate button

### and will get the price in totall amount textbox

i tried this one :-

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    textBox1.Text* listBox1.SelectedItem();

}
```

Comment: Simply follow your debugger. It tell you everything that is wrong. I you google any of those errors you have you will find right away your answer.

Comment: What you tried does a calculation, but does nothing with the result.  Did you mean to assign the result ?  Also, I would expect something like `listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].Value` instead of `listBox1.SelectedItem()`

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform a multiplication (*), you need to have a numerical value on the left and right.  The (*) function is a pure return type so you also need to assign it to something.

EDIT: I realized too late that you were using a ListBox.  Just remember to cast the selected item value to a decimal (or parse it)

so, a few steps.
1: Get the numerical value in textBox1:

```
int quantity;
if(!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out quantity)){
  MessageBox.Show("Only numbers are allowed in Quantity", "Error");
}
```

Two things are happening here.  We are trying to parse a string into an integer.  Not all strings can be parsed (i.e. "One") and some can (i.e. "1").  If the text cannot be parsed then we want to warn the user.
We also have an "out" parameter on int.TryParse.  If the parse is successful then the value of quantity is set to the int value.  We kill two birds with one stone.

2: Get the price of the selected item.
You can be clever with comboboxes as the items are "objects" and the text-on-form comes from that objects "ToString()" function.  You can store anything in that object, but you would need to cast to make any sense of it.  For now, lets assume that you have a "Product" class?:

```
public class Product{
   private string _name;
   public decimal Price {get;}

   public Product(string name, decimal price){
      _name = name;
      Price = price;
   }
   public override string ToString(){
     return _name;
   }
}
```

We can now populate out combobox with some items:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(new Product("Pizza", 5.99));
comboBox1.Items.Add(new Product("Burger", 2.99));
```

Now we can use a cast to get that class back from the comboBox:

```
var selectedProduct = (Product) comboBox1.SelectItem;
```

Then you can do your multiplication:

```
var total = quantity * selectedProduct.Price;
```

Hope that helps ^_^